# Why am I getting "PG::NotNullViolation null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint" whenever I login in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

After dumping, downloading and pg_restoring a DB from Heroku, any time I try to login in my rails application I get the above error.

It somehow seems that the user id is seen as nil (even though I can see an id value in the DB).

I also read that it may be due to the id being a simple int instead of a serial, however, as you can see in my schema:

```
create_table "users", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "provider"
    t.string "uid"
    t.boolean "admin", default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "affiliate_approved", default: false, null: false
    t.integer "cart_id"
    t.float "rev_share"
    t.boolean "notice", default: false, null: false
    t.string "iban"
    t.string "piva"
    t.string "invitation_token"
    t.datetime "invitation_created_at"
    t.datetime "invitation_sent_at"
    t.datetime "invitation_accepted_at"
    t.integer "invitation_limit"
    t.string "invited_by_type"
    t.integer "invited_by_id"
    t.integer "invitations_count", default: 0
    t.string "username"
    t.string "slug"
    t.integer "enrolls_count", default: 0
    t.integer "partner_id"
    t.string "country"
    t.integer "referrer"
    t.boolean "gdpr_marketing"
    t.boolean "privacy_policy"
    t.boolean "subscription", default: false
    t.date "account_created_at"
    t.boolean "profilazione"
    t.boolean "terms_and_conditions"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["invitation_token"], name: "index_users_on_invitation_token", unique: true
    t.index ["invitations_count"], name: "index_users_on_invitations_count"
    t.index ["invited_by_id"], name: "index_users_on_invited_by_id"
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true
  end
```

And it seems that the id is used already as serial.

Do you have any idea of what may be going wrong? This application is live in production with a couple of thousands of users who aren't being impacted by this issue, which makes me think there's something wrong with my local PG setup.

**Edit - full error message**

```
PG::NotNullViolation at /auth/google_oauth2/callback
ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, 9367, 127.0.0.1, 2018-09-17 09:51:59.463125, 2018-09-17 09:51:59.463125).
```

**Edit - more findings**

In user.rb (the model file) there's an after_update hook where the following is executed:

```
def change_log
  UserChange.create(ip_request: current_sign_in_ip, user: self)
end
```

This is so that we can track everything a user changes along with their IP (GDPR reasons).

After commenting that out, it all works alright and my user gets logged in as planned

Comment: Can you update the question with the full error that appeared in the server when you try to login?

Comment: I'd rule out that you're not somehow trying to create a new use and force the id to nil first. Could be an error with your authentication code for example.

Comment: @Pavan just updated

Comment: @TomDunning - the only thing that I find odd is that this is happening just on my local machine. The other devs in the team are able to signup/login with no PG errors whatsoever

Comment: @AndreaRocca You’re sure there’s no data in there with a null id? I’d try dropping the db then creating it and seeing the data again if it were me. If that doesn’t fix it (and your seeds definitely have ids) then it has to be a new record it’s trying to create

Comment: @TomDunning - I did drop the DB and unfortunately the same has happened. I did find out however that the error is cause by a specific line (added to the question).

Comment: If you stick that in an `if self.persisted?` does the error still occur? Check the constraints on the UserChange table (rather than the User table). It’s worth mentioning that you’re not supposed to store that IP under GDPR. Secondly, there’s a gem called audited which does a lot of this for you and can be applied to multiple tables: https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @TomDunning thanks for your inputs! I believe I found the issue in the UserChange table (and a few others).

For some reason I had a bunch of tables using id: integer in the schema. I changed that to serial and refreshed it and it worked indeed.

You can add an answer so that I can set it as accepted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be a callback to another table which is trying to persist with a null ID. Check for callbacks and the schema for any related tables. In your case this was the UserChange table.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error after pulling a copy of the DB from Heroku:

`PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains ...etc`

It was happening every time I tried to create a new record.  I'm guessing that when you log in, your app is creating a new record somewhere (possibly some login tracking/logging you are doing?) that is triggering the error.  If you can't access the app through a web browser, you could try opening up the Rails console and see what happens if you try to create a new record directly.  If you still get the error, the issue is not actually with your login but with your DB.

The issue for me was that I was using a different version of Postgres on my dev machine to the version on Heroku that created the dump file.  After switching to the matching version of Postgres an re-pulling the DB, everything is working as expected again.

If you're using Postgres on Mac, when you add a new Postgres server, you can choose which version of Postgres it should use.  You want to make your development and production environments as similar as possible so you definitely want to make sure that your DB versions match.